# Django REST JSONWebTokenAuthentication + Angular (Authorization details not provided)

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, authorization, django-rest-framework-jwt

For a couple of days i've been trying to get this rather simple authentication setup to work.

I'm using the Django REST plugin 'django-rest-framework-jwt' to do JSON web token authentication.

When CURLing the API, it works as supposed.

[image]

Though, when issuing the requests through my Angular application; i'm constantly getting an Unauthorized error with the details 'Authorization details not provided'. However, when crawling the requests, one can clearly see that it is present (the token within the request is valid, as i've used it within the CURL':

[image]

I'm injecting the authentication header via a interceptor I wrote; which looks like this:

```
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const auth = this.session.authorization;

    if (!auth) {
      return next.handle(req);
    } else {
      const newReq = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: auth,
        },
      });

      return next.handle(newReq);
    }
  }
```

Further, the settings of the JWT_AUTH settings are defined as follows:

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_encode_handler',

    'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_decode_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler',

    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'auth.views.jwt_response_payload_handler',

    'JWT_SECRET_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'JWT_GET_USER_SECRET_KEY': None,
    'JWT_PUBLIC_KEY': None,
    'JWT_PRIVATE_KEY': None,
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'JWT_VERIFY': True,
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
    'JWT_LEEWAY': 0,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=300),
    'JWT_AUDIENCE': None,
    'JWT_ISSUER': None,

    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600),

    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'Bearer',
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None,
}
```

The framework settings are as follows:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Any suggestions on this? I'm not sure whats going on here.

*EDIT*

Request/response headers in the network tab:

[image]

Comment: Check in the actual request headers in the network tab on the Chrome Dev Tools and add what you're seeing.

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: Yours is a Request Interceptor, right? Why not look for the Header in the `Request Headers` section instead of the `Response Headers`

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to tell here? I posted both the response and the request headers in the screenshot above.

Comment: What I'm saying is, since you've created a Request Interceptor, to add an Authorization Header to your **REQUESTS**, there should be an `Authorization` header in your Request Headers section. Which is not as of now.

Comment: Indeed, but I can't seem to grasp why. When printing the object in console it is definitely there. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181425/discussion-between-siddajmera-and-iso).

Answer (score 0):

So, end it had nothing to do with the Angular app, but the sever not accepting CORS. Fix it by the explanation in the following post:

https://www.techiediaries.com/django-cors/